# Using puppeteer.js to scrape kijiji cars. Cant get values of different divs all into one place

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

Pretty confusing title, but I dont know how to really ask it any better.

I essentially am trying to get both the TITLE and the PRICE of each listing on the page and store them both into one place.

My current code is looking like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

function run() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250,
        devtools: true,
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
      await page.goto(
        "https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-vehicles/city-of-toronto/honda-civic/k0c27l1700273",
        { waitUntil: "networkidle2" }
      );
      let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let results = [];
        // to get the titles 
        let titles = document.querySelectorAll(
          "div.regular-ad > div.clearfix > div.info > div.info-container > div.title"
        );
        titles.forEach((title) => {
          results.push({
            title: title.innerText,
          });
        });
        // to get the price
        let prices = document.querySelectorAll(
          "div.regular-ad > div.clearfix > div.info > div.info-container > div.price"
        );
        prices.forEach((price) => {
          results.push({
            price: price.innerText,
          });
        });

        return results;
      });
      browser.close();
      return resolve(urls);
    } catch (e) {
      return reject(e);
    }
  });
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

However my output s coming out in seperate objects - first an array of all the titles then an array of all the prices, I want to have the title and price match inside the same object then move onto the next one!

Answer (score 0):

That should look something like:

```
page.evaluate(() => {
  return [...document.querySelectorAll('div.info-container')].map(div => {
    return {
      title: div.querySelector('.title').innerText,
      pricee: div.querySelector('.price').innerText
    }
  })
})
```